# Reading out version of cc1plus (SCons script-based)

Tags: python, gcc, scons

Actually I'm trying to read out the version of my cc1plus executable in windows. This is a rather simple job: 
`cc1plus -version`

I need this for a scons script (Tool), to integrate an ARM cross compiler. Because of that I directly call cc1plus instead of using some compiler driver. There is no useful compiler driver available.

Back to my problem: When I'm calling "cc1plus -version" on cmd I get a version string back, but cc1plus isn't terminated. Instead it is continuously executed. I have to kill cc1plus with CRTL+D. For my script this is a problem.

In the following a snippet of my cmd:

`C:\DevTools\CrossWorks_for_ARM_2.3\bin>cc1plus -version`

`GNU C++ (GCC) version 4.7.3 20121207 (release) [ARM/embedded-4_7-branch revision 194305] (arm-unknown-eabi)
        compiled by GNU C version 3.4.4 (mingw special), GMP version 4.3.2, MPFR version 2.4.2, MPC version 0.8.1
GGC heuristics: --param ggc-min-expand=100 --param ggc-min-heapsize=131072`

`^C`

`C:\DevTools\CrossWorks_for_ARM_2.3\bin>`

Is there any trick to terminate cc1plus after retrieving the version? For me it is rather incomprehensible why cc1plus isn't terminating.

Comment: How are you executing cc1plus? From SCons via python?

Comment: Exactly! But I also tried it directly via cmd. The behaviour (not terminating) is the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to give it something to compile. Maybe be redirecting input from `null:` (not sure if that's correct for windows). Though if so, that looks like a moderately strange compiler

Comment: Thanks for your hint! This works: `cc1plus -quit -version NUL`. I expected the version is printed on stdout, but cc1plus prints it on stderr. This was another issue.